# How To Find Time Difference using Chrono library in Rust

Tags: time, rust

I have a Rust program where I want to do some simple benchmarking with start time and end time!

```rust
use chrono::{NaiveTime, Utc};

fn main() {
    let start_time: NaiveTime = Utc::now().time();
    let end_time: NaiveTime = Utc::now().time();
    println!("Total time taken to run is {}", end_time - start_time);
}
```

The code above prints as:

```
Total time taken to run is PT520.532696S
```

I guess it is 520 seconds if I'm not wrong, but how can I convert that into minutes? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple look to the [doc](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.6/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveTime.html#impl-Sub%3CNaiveTime%3E) give the [answer](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.6/chrono/struct.Duration.html#method.num_minutes):

```rust
use chrono::Utc;

fn main() {
    let start_time = Utc::now().time();
    let end_time = Utc::now().time();
    let diff = end_time - start_time;
    println!("Total time taken to run is {}", diff.num_minutes());
}
```

but be aware that it's not a good way to mesure time in a monotonic way, this code could show -5 minutes if user change the system date somehow. Also call `time()` remove the information of the date, and this is strange when you use chrono because generally you don't want to ignore the date so just remove `time()` call.

Answer (score 7):

It seems the accepted answer has some potential flaws.

A potentially better way as recommended in the [rust nursery](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/datetime/duration.html)

is the following:

```
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use std::thread;

fn expensive_function() {
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
}

fn main() {
    let start = Instant::now();
    expensive_function();
    let duration = start.elapsed();

    println!("Time elapsed in expensive_function() is: {:?}", duration);
}
```